# How long is FB.Auth.parseSignedRequest available?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using `FB.Auth.parseSignedRequest` results in a warning message in debugger.

```
The method FB.Auth.parseSignedRequest is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed.
```

How long will this method be available in `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on it being there tomorrow, because it might just have been removed.
It will most definitely be gone by next Tuesday :)